# Sed, Match all lines between 2 patterns (inclusive), and then put the second match at the top

Tags: awk, sed

This is what I need to do:

Input: (Python)

```py
## This is a function,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
def function_name(x):
    return x + 1
```

Output: (Markdown)

```markdown
## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

So far I got:

```sh
sed -n '/## /,/def/ { /## \|def/ p }' TEST.py | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed 's/(.*)\(.*\)://'
```

Which produces:

```markdown
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
function_name
```

There are 2 conditions:

1.- The lines in between the "##" and the "def" that don't match any of these patterns, should be ignored.

Example:

Input: (Python)

```py
## This is a function,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
# This is a normal comment, nothing to see here! (ignored)
def function_name(x):
    return x + 1
```

Output: (Markdown)

```markdown
## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

2.- The second pattern has to be generalized, for example, instead of using "def", let's say I want to use "class".

Input: (Python)

```py
## This is a class,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
# This is a normal comment, nothing to see here! (ignored)
class class_name:
    __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Output: (Markdown)

```markdown
## class_name
This is a class,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```sh
$ awk '/^## / { comment = comment substr($0, 4) "\n" }
       /^def / { printf "## %s\n%s", substr($0, 5, index($0, "(") - 5), comment
                 comment = "" }' TEST.py  
## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

Appends all lines starting with `##` to a variable, and when it sees a line starting with `def` , prints the function name and the variable with the earlier lines, and then blanks that variable to start again.

---

GNU `sed` version using the hold space to store the comment lines:

```sh
$ sed -n -e '/^## / { s/^## //; H }' -e '/^def / { s/^def \([^(]*\).*/## \1/; G; s/\n\n/\n/; p; z; x }' TEST.py
## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

Comment: That *is* a one-liner, though if you want one actual line, you don't need the linebreaks in the quoted argument. Just looks uglier that way, and you'll need a semicolon between the two statements in the second block.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after implementing it

Comment: Although, there are 2 little problems that I thought could be generalized, but I think I'll have to put them anyways

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer, srry for not being explicit before

Comment: @CarloAugustoBagnoliGomez My versions skip the comment lines that don't start with `##` .  For the second new thing, add more examples?

Comment: Impressive use of sed hold space (H).   I've got to admit I didn't understand the code starting with G; - but I will review GNU sed documentation for some help there.  I definitely learned something.

Comment: Thank you, you taught me a lot, I'll take it from here. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box (use `a-zA-Z0-9` instead of `[:alnum:]` if your awk doesn't support POSIX character classes):

```
$ cat tst.awk
sub(/^## */,"") {
    cmts = cmts $0 ORS
    next
}

sub(/^[[:alnum:]_]+ */,"") {
    sub(/[^[:alnum:]_].*/,"")
    print "##", $0
    print cmts
    cmts = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada

## function_name
This is a function,
its purpose is... yada yada yada

## class_name
This is a class,
its purpose is... yada yada yada
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
## This is a function,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
def function_name(x):
    return x + 1

## This is a function,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
# This is a normal comment, nothing to see here! (ignored)
def function_name(x):
    return x + 1

## This is a class,
## its purpose is... yada yada yada
# This is a normal comment, nothing to see here! (ignored)
class class_name:
    __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
/##/ { 
  gsub( "## *", "" )  
  previous[ ++lines ] = $0 
}
/def/ { 
  gsub( "def ", "")  
  gsub( "[(].*","" ) 
  print "## " $0  
  for (x = 1 ; x <= lines ; x++ ) 
    print previous[x] 
  lines = 0 
}
' TEST.py
```

Looks like Shawn beat me to the answer.  The answers are similar, they differ mainly by how the lines are accumulated.  Shawn accumulates the previous lines in a single variable (comment) whereas I accumulate them in an array.

I think Shawn may have additional assumptions in the code, like every ## has a single space after it or function names start in the 5th character on a line and that ## and def both appear at the beginning of the line.

I think that I should definitely add some anchors, too, since /def/ may have a lot of unintended matches, so /^def/ may be much better.

What's interesting is that we both ignored using sed, since I personally have no idea how to work with variables in sed.  I'm interested in seeing if other solutions will be available from the community that are pure sed.

Comment: I added a sed version to my answer.

Comment: Yes, you should be using anchors. Also, all of your `gsub()`s should be `sub()`s as you only ever want to do something with the first match and if you do it with all of the matches on the line then you can corrupt comments like `## I prefer 4 hashes, #### is clearer` or function names like `def mydef ()`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^##/{h;:a;n;/^##/{H;ba}
        s/^(def|class)( \w*).*/##\2/;Ta;G;s/^## ?//2mgp}' file
```

If the current line does not begins `##` do nothing.

Replace the hold space by the current line.

Fetch the next line.

If line begins `##` append it to the hold space and repeat above.

If the following line does not begin `def` or `class` repeat as above.

Otherwise, manipulate the function/class name into a markdown heading, append the comments from the hold space, remove the `##` from the comments and print.

Comment: That `s/## ?//2mgp` is a thing of beauty.